# Is there a term to refer to the potential of something to be repeated (or not)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like, say an ordered pair can have repeats such as (1,1), whereas a set can't - {1,1} isn't a valid set.

I don't mean a word to describe whether a thing has or has not been repeated, but whether it's possible for a particular thing to be repeated. (1,0) is an ordered pair without any repeat elements, but because it's an ordered pair, it's elements *could've* been repeated. A set's elements would never have this possibility.

The closest word I could come up with is just "repetitive", but that's not quite right - saying (1,0) was repetitive would likely raise eyebrows, so I've since dismissed it.

Comment: The Java keyword is *Iterable*, a related adjective is *iterative*.

Comment: Not familiar with Java, but, in Python, saying something is Iterable simply means that it can be iterated over, such as in a for loop. More practically, that it is broken into discrete elements.

Comment: Most pythons (if not all?) run on JVM. Therefore, *iterable* is the same betw Java and Python.

Comment: Jython does, the rest don't. And that doesn't really work because we're talking about concepts - in Python, saying something is iterable says nothing about its potential to repeat elements.

Comment: So, *Iterable* is the word. It is an interface used to declare that an item can be *repeated*, and the Iterable interface forces it to implement properties to allow it to be repeated - You don't have to repeat it. It merely has all the potentials and trappings implemented to be used for its repeatability.

Comment: One might classify the Mona Lisa painting as ***unique***, but assuming really accurate 3d printers will be around "real soon now", there could be any number of perfect copies before long. Each of those will always be worth less than the *original*, but the distinguishing feature of all those *equivalent* copies is that they would be [***fungible***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungibility). The original is "unrepeatable" in that there can only ever be one of it. All the others, up to any arbitrary number of repetitions, are *interchangeable, **repeatable***.

Comment: Recommended migration to math.se

Comment: A loosely defined expression like *set of non-unique elements* has been used, esp., outside the field of mathematics. However, as your context is not known, I'm not sure if you can use a contradiction like 'set' and 'nonunique' in a single noun-phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual definition of a set is something along the lines of:

> a group of distinct entities regarded as a unit

If it were me, I would just say that something that *can't* be repeated is *distinct*, whereas *indistinct* could refer to something that could or has been repeated. You could also use *unique*, but I don't have a good one-word term for the opposite, beside *non-unique*.

You could also just use *repeatable*, but that doesn't really seem like what you're going for, since I normally don't here that except when describing actions.

That said, if you're talking to people familiar with mathy concepts and you didn't mention specifically that a group was made of unique/distinct elements, it would probably be assumed that the elements could be repeated.

Comment: I like distinct. The only issue is that I'd like a word that I could use to refer to the collection, rather than it's elements.

Comment: And by that I mean that, with distinct, I would say "the collection's elements are distinct" or something along those lines, rather than "the collection is distinct" because that makes it sound like you're comparing two separate collections and declaring them distinct from each other.

Comment: Then you call it a set ;)

Comment: Actually, going from that, you could refer to it as "setlike" or "set-compliant", and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your formulas, zeros and ones, but maybe "recurring" would work? recurrable?

Comment: Recurring has the same problem as repetitive. Recurrable sounds closer to what I mean, but I can't find any definitions, so I'm not sure if it's actually a commonly used word.

Comment: And, really, the only math you need to know to understand my examples is that both sets and ordered pairs contain numbers, and ordered pairs can repeat the numbers the contain, while sets can't.

Comment: Recurrable isn't a real word, but there are 31,000 google results for it. Will be in the dictionary soon enough :)

Repeatable doesn't fit? -- edit: oops this was already suggested. So?

Comment: Why do you think this would work, and why it would be a good/ useful answer?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for "repeatable"?

> possible to do or make again: repeatable test results

source: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/repeatable